# Rails Controller Namespacing/Module Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, namespaces, models

I have an API controller for a model in my rails project.

The API controller is as follows:

```
#app/controllers/api/v1/airbnb/customers_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
    class CustomersController < Api::V1::BaseApiController
      def create
        @airbnb_customer = Airbnb::Customer.new
        @json_request['airbnb_customer']['client_id'] = @client.id
        update_values :@customer, @json_request['airbnb_customer']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem comes when creating the new `airbnb_customer`:

```
NameError in Api::V1::Airbnb::CustomersController#create
uninitialized constant Api::V1::Airbnb::Customer
```

I do not know how to prevent the Api::V1 scope from being applied when calling `Airbnb::Customer.new`
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My models are located in `app/models/airbnb.rb` and `app/models/airbnb/customer.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding :: before Airbnb should accesses the 'root' of the namespace tree, so you should add

```
::Airbnb::Customer.new
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Don't know why I could not find that information when I was looking.